# Prove Line Circumscribed Circle; Incircle; Excircle

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles

How can I prove, that the circumscribed circle of a triangle does exactly cross the middle of the line that goes from the incenter of the incircle of the triangle to the excenter of the excircle of the triangle?

Answer (score 1):

By angle chasing, you can prove the statement.  Here are some steps to do so.

Let $ABC$ be a triangle with circumcircle $\Gamma$.  Write $I$ and $I_a$, respectively, for the incenter and the excenter opposite to the vertex $A$ of the triangle $ABC$.  Denote by $M_a$ the midpoint of the arc $BC$ of $\Gamma$ that does not contain $A$.

1. Show that $\angle IBI_a=\dfrac{\pi}{2}=\angle ICI_a$.  As a consequence, $IBI_aC$ is a cyclic quadrilateral.  If $\omega_a$ is the circumcircle of the quadrilateral $IBI_aC$, then $II_a$ is a diameter of $\omega_a$.
2. Check that $M_aB=M_aC$.  This is easy.
3. Prove that $A$, $I$, $M_a$, and $I_a$ are collinear.  This is also easy.  (Recall that $I$ and $I_a$ are on the internal angular bisector of $\angle BAC$.)
4. Use (2) and (3) to verify that $M_aB=M_aI$.  This implies that $M_a$ is the circumcenter of the triangle $IBC$.  However, as $I$, $B$, $I_a$, and $C$ are concyclic, the claim follows.