# $P$ is the incenter of $\triangle ABC$.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, inverse

Let $\triangle ABC$ and $\omega$ the circumscribed circle and $P$ inside the triangle and $\omega_1$, $\omega_2$, $\omega_3$ the circumscribed circles of the triangles $\triangle PAB, \triangle PBC,  \triangle PAC$ and $O_1, O_2, O_3$ the centres of $\omega_1$, $\omega_2$, $\omega_3$.

If $O_1, O_2, O_3$ lie on $\omega$ show that $P$ is the incenter of $\triangle ABC$.
[image]

I tried to make an inversion around $P$ of radius $1$. I denote $A^*$ the inverse of $A$ and so on. I have to prove that $\angle PAB=\angle PAC$ and this is equivalent to prove that $\angle PB^*A^*=\angle PC^*A^*$. Now I am stuck. I am not sure that is ok my picture after inversion.[image]

Comment: You are overcomplicating the problem.  If $O_1$, $O_2$, and $O_3$ lies on $\omega$, then they are respectively the midpoints of the arcs $AB$, $BC$, and $CA$.  Therefore, it suffices to show that the incenter $I$ of the triangle $ABC$ satisfies $O_1I=O_1A=O_1B$, $O_2I=O_2B=O_2C$, and $O_3I=O_3C=O_3A$ (which can be done via angle-chasing).  Thus, $I$ is a common intersection of $\omega_1$, $\omega_2$, and $\omega_3$.  This will prove $P=I$.

Comment: @Plato  Which software did you use to draw the figure?  I like the font.

Comment: @ WE Tutorial School It's Geogebra but as a phone app from PlayStore

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2997457/proove-line-circumscribed-circle-incircle-excircle.